# Issue: NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: python, django

So I'm currently building an online webshop for my school project. In the webshop, the user should be able to submit a review on each product. Tho I'm having issues when trying to submit the review. It gives me this error:

```
NOT NULL constraint failed:
```

Ive been stuck on this for about 15 hours I cant seem to solve it. I would appreciate all the help I can get.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (NOT NULL constraint failed: products_reviewrating.user_id) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/workspace/webster00/products/views.py", line 91, in submit_review
    newreview.save()
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 726, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 763, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 868, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 906, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1270, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1410, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /products/submit_review/6/
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: products_reviewrating.user_id
```

Views.py

```
def submit_review(request, product_id):
    print(f'product_id: {product_id}')
    url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
            reviews = ReviewRating.objects.filter(user=request.user.userprofile, product=product).first()
            form = ReviewForm(request.POST, instance=reviews)
            newreview = form.save(commit=False)
            newreview.product = product
            newreview.save()
            form.save()

            messages.success(request, 'Thank you! Your review has been updated')
            return redirect(url)
        except ReviewRating.DoesNotExist:
            form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                data = ReviewRating()
                data.subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
                data.rating = form.cleaned_data['rating']
                data.review = form.cleaned_data['review']
                data.ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
                data.product_id = product_id
                data.user_id = request.user.id
                data.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Thank you! Your review has been submited.')
                return redirect(url)
```

The Review is also not showing in the django admin.

Comment: Can you share your `ReviewForm`, likely this can be simplified *a lot*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably simplify the view a lot with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


@login_required
def submit_review(request, product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    userprofile = request.user.userprofile
    review = ReviewRating.objects.filter(
        user=userprofile, product=product
    ).first()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        action = ('submitted', 'updated')[review is not None]
        form = ReviewForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=review)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.product_id = product_id
            form.instance.user = userprofile
            form.instance.ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
            form.save()
            messages.success(
                request, f'Thank you! Your review has been {action}.'
            )
            return redirect(URL)
    else:
        form = ReviewForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=review)
    return render(request, 'name-of-some-template.html', {'form': form})
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful tips! You are a legend! Tho im getting an error when trying out the code of:  
First argument to get_object_or_404() must be a Model, Manager, or QuerySet, not 'method'.

Comment: @Cyborgsonny: I forgot to remove the `.objects.get` part :P

Comment: Im literally almost crying, i swear to god! Ive been stuck on this for 20 hours..... THANK YOU SOOO MUCH BROTHER!!

Answer (score 3):

You're not assigning all of the fields (`user` in this case) in the `newreview` case.

Add

```
newreview.user = request.user
```

before the `save` - and you may need to repeat this for other fields you haven't dealt with.

Comment: When i do that i get the error:  
Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: admin>>": "ReviewRating.user" must be a "UserProfile" instance.

If its not to much to ask, could you help show how you would di it?